# How to make the items in a variable a single item

Tags: applescript

Lets say I have a variable Q set to {"a", "b", "c"}
how can I make it so that AppleScript takes the items of Q and turns it into a single item so that Q is now set to {"abc"}?

Comment: @calum_b AppleScript questions are perfectly on-topic, no need to bounce them to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have: `set Q to {"a", "b", "c"}`

You can then do:

```
set Q to (Q as string) as list
```

- `(Q as string)` *coerces* the `Q` *list* `{"a", "b", "c"}` into a *string*, `"abc"`, and `as list` turns the *string* into a *list item* assigned to `Q`.

Not necessary, but if you also add:

```
return Q
```

Just to see what it returns, it will return:

```
{"abc"}
```

Which is what you wanted.